# Right to Left alignment not working in Python Word Cloud

Tags: python, word-cloud

There's this library, [`persian-word-cloud`](https://github.com/mehotkhan/persian-word-cloud), which is a fork of [`word_cloud`](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud).

In the example directory of this library, there's this example, [with_mask.py](https://github.com/mehotkhan/persian-word-cloud/blob/master/example/with_mask.py), which uses [twitter-logo.jpg](https://github.com/mehotkhan/persian-word-cloud/blob/master/example/twitter-logo.jpg) to create a word cloud from [persian.txt](https://github.com/mehotkhan/persian-word-cloud/blob/master/example/persian.txt).

The output should look like this:

[image]

But when I install the package using `pip install persian_wordcloud` and run the same script, the output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the direction of the words are wrong. How can I fix this?

Also, the problem seems to be with version `3.8.1` of Python, because if I run it with version `3.7.4` everything works well.

Comment: A workaround would be to mirror the mask first and then the final image again.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the words aren't mirrored, their direction is LTR instead of RTL. I don't think mirroring is gonna fix it. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Doesn't work https://i.imgur.com/mjdRq9f.png

Comment: I see. Sorry, I can’t read Persian and didn’t notice the details.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No worries.

Comment: It looks like the [reshaper](https://mpcabd.xyz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/) is working but the BiDi is not. Do you have another project that uses both these libraries?

Comment: Can you try on your local Python if this works? `from bidi.algorithm import get_display; print (get_display('hello world = سلام به دنیا'))` -- as far as I can tell, it works on my Python 3.8.1. (Note for others willing to try: your *browser* may already write the text correctly! The rightmost (first!) character should be `س` *seen*.)

Comment: @usr2564301 Sorry I didn't respond earlier, but this is the output, using Python 3.8.2: `hello world = ایند هب مالس`

Comment: Amir, if you can *reliably* pin-point the problem is with `bidi`, you should add your test code for that in the question. (Since you have two Pythons installed: don't forget to cross-test *everything*.) At least it'll bump your question up with a valid edit. If there is something wrong with `bidi` in the latest Python, finding out what it is caused by is an important issue.