# Python arabic text returns in right-to-left orientation instead of left-to-right

Tags: python, flask, arabic, arabic-support, bidi

I'm working on a python project with Python(3.6) and Flask in which I have to return a text in Arabic. When I print the text in the console it works well but when I return it as response it's order changes to right-to-left.

Here's what I have tried:

```
from odoa import ODOA
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from flask import Flask
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_an_ayah():
    odoa = ODOA()
    surah = odoa.get_random_surah(lang='en')
    text = surah.ayah.decode("utf-8")
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)    # correct its shape
    arabic_text = get_display(reshaped_text, base_dir='R')
    print(arabic_text)
    translation = str(surah.translate)
    sound_file_url = str(surah.sound)
    reference = str(str(surah.surah_number) + ':' + str(surah.ayah_number))
    response_dict = {
        'text': arabic_text,
        'translation': translation,
        'sound': sound_file_url,
        'ref': reference
    }

    return response_dict
```

result for `print(arabix_text` is:

[image]

and here's how its in response:

```
{
    "ref": "94:2",
    "sound": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/semarketir/quranjson/master/source/audio/094/002.mp3",
    "text": "ﻙﺭﺯﻭ ﻚﻨﻋ ﺎﻨﻌﺿﻭﻭ",
    "translation": "And lift from you your burden."
}
```

how can I get the correct orientation for Arabic text?

Comment: What happens when you reverse the string? Does reversing the string solves the problem?

Comment: I tried that... just reverse the letters

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286526/right-to-left-alignment-not-working-in-python-word-cloud – but that seems tied quite specific to Python 3.8.

Comment: I'm using Python(3.6)

Comment: But do note that that question is still open and the cause has not yet been determined. You could run the test I proposed to see if the circumstances are similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need [arabic_reshaper](https://pypi.org/project/arabic-reshaper/) and [python-bidi](https://pypi.org/project/python-bidi/) ?

Try the following code instead:

```py
from odoa import ODOA
from flask import Flask
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_an_ayah():
    odoa = ODOA()
    surah = odoa.get_random_surah(lang='en')
    text = surah.ayah.decode("utf-8")
    translation = str(surah.translate)
    sound_file_url = str(surah.sound)
    reference = str(str(surah.surah_number) + ':' + str(surah.ayah_number))
    response_dict = {
        'text': text,
        'translation': translation,
        'sound': sound_file_url,
        'ref': reference
    }

    return response_dict
```

The output text will be with Arabic diacritics and Quranic annotation. If you want to remove them, use the following regex replacement:

```py
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(
    '['
    '\u0610-\u061a'
    '\u064b-\u065f'
    '\u0670'
    '\u06d6-\u06dc'
    '\u06df-\u06e8'
    '\u06ea-\u06ed'
    '\u08d4-\u08e1'
    '\u08d4-\u08ed'
    '\u08e3-\u08ff'
    ']',
)

letters_only_text = re.sub(PATTERN, '', text)
```

See [Arabic Unicode Chart](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) and [Arabic Extended-A Unicode Chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U08A0.pdf) for more info about those replacements.