# Arabic text not printing correctlly python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, unicode, arabic, python-unicode

**This question is not duplicate, Please DO NOT CLOSE IT.**

I edited my post for more detail:

Can fix this problem?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x100+400+100')
text1 = 'السلام عليكم'
root.title(text1)
label1 = Label(root, text=text1).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't python but your editor, command line, etc. because it cannot show unicode characters?

Comment: This seems like an issue with your editor, when i run your code it prints just fine.

Comment: Using [this online python interpreter](https://repl.it/languages/python3), it doesn't have a problem showing your characters

Comment: I think that i have a problem with my python interpreter... is it possible???

Comment: How are you running this code? directly in python console?

Comment: I try it with python console, and try to put it in file.py and execute it with terminal, and get the sane problem

Comment: also i try it with tkinter i have 2 result: if i used it as title it work well but when i use it as label give me same problem of console

Comment: maybe have a look at......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631544/python-arabic-text-returns-in-right-to-left-orientation-instead-of-left-to-right

Comment: thanx, but this not help me.

Comment: Well given how little code you have posted and little detail you have given its hard for anyone to really help you.

Comment: I give this full code , can you fix it?

Comment: The issue is a rendering issue. The python interpreter doesn't render text. It just shuffles around buffers of character sequences. It's your editor / console that renders the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different editor or compiler. Your editor might not be showing the correct Unicode. 
Or try to code UTF-8 in your codes and/or check your editor settings.

Comment: I use gedit editor for coding: https://www11.0zz0.com/2020/06/13/17/842312830.png

Comment: This link doesn't work. I would suggest you use something else. A good choice for beginners would be [IDLE](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-idle). If you want something more advanced, then use [vim](https://www.vim.org/). (it's what I use as well).

Answer (score 0):

سلام

Since Arabic script is right to left, you can use the libraries: https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper and https://github.com/MeirKriheli/python-bidi

Something like this can work:

```
from tkinter import *

import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x100+400+100')
text1 = 'السلام عليكم'
root.title(text1)
label1 = Label(root, text=get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(text1))).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWgry.png)